# "DECLARE is not valid at this position expecting END" when using DECLARE EXIT HANDLER

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Version: 5.7

I have a MySQL stored procedure that when I added a EXIT HANDLER is failing with the following error in the tool tip:

> DECLARE is not valid at this position expecting END

SQL Workbench returns this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION    BEGIN
> ROLLBACK;    EXIT PROCEDURE;  ' at line 17

If I remove the code it creates with no issues.  Below is code with elements renamed:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `MyProcedureName`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `MyProcedureName`(
    IN var1 int,
    IN var2 int,
    IN var3 int,
    IN var4 VARCHAR(45),
    IN var5 VARCHAR(5000),
    IN var6 VARCHAR(5000),
    IN var7 VARCHAR(5000),
    IN var8 VARCHAR(5000)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE var9 int;
    DECLARE var10 int;
    DECLARE var11 int;
    START TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            EXIT PROCEDURE;
        END;
        
    <Insert statements>
    
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9508b5268bfc322575c2e51d5b0ecd8e) Handler after declare section but before START Transaction

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I thought I had tried that but did retry on your suggestion.  However got an error on EXIT PROCEDURE.  I noticed that the EXIT PROCEDURE from your code.  Am I correct assuming that it is unnecessary since this is an EXIT handler?

Comment: 1) EXIT PROCEDURE statement not exists in SQL 2) It not needed - the handler is EXIT one itself, so after its execution the procedure will be finished.